# OwnerID in Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, configuration, standard-field, record-owner

Is it possible that the standard field **OwnerID** be deleted in a custom object? Because we're having a problem now due to its missing/deleted.
[image]

These are the standard fields under the custom object that we are using.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? how can the owner id be missed or deleted? The owner is mandatory on any record. please explain.

Comment: We don't know how it was missed/deleted. Please see the screenshot above @NitishSinghal

Comment: What is the relation of having a master-detail relationship in a missing standard field? @RedDevil

Comment: My bad @JMRAF69 missed the missing part

Comment: Can you show us all the custom fields too? If this object is a child in an M/D relationship then it will not have an owner. It will be owned by its parent's owner.

Answer (score 3):

If the object is a child of a master-detail relationship (has a master-detail lookup field) then it wont have an ownerId. If you added a master-detail field, the ownerId standard field would have been removed.

The sharing would be controlled by the parent object's OWD settings. If it is a junction object (has 2 master-detail lookups) then both parent object settings contribute to the child sharing settings - for example both parent objects need to be Public Read-Only for the child object to be Public Read-Only.